# selenium-ide pass variable from test suite to test

Tags: selenium-ide

Is there any way to pass a variable from the suite to the test in selenium ide? I need to have change the baseURL half way through my tests and I'd like to be able to set that once for all the tests

I've tried using storeEval and setting it that way.

I'm guessing the only way might be to create a userExtension and set the variable there

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is really a problem that should be solved by moving to Selenium-RC, you may want to take a look at the Data Driven plugin http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SEL/datadriven. This lets you supply an XML file with data to be used in tests.

Comment: I ended up using the flow control plugin instead but this really is the way to go